# Static resources can't be loaded, what's wrong in this Nginx setup?

Tags: nginx, centos7, static-content

In a Docker container running PHP71-FPM and Nginx I have the following setup for Nginx:

```
server {
    listen      80  default_server;
    listen      81  default_server http2 proxy_protocol; ## Needed when behind HAProxy with SSL termination + HTTP/2 support
    listen      443 default_server ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/ssl/dummy.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/ssl/dummy.key;

    root        /data/www/demos/jqgrid;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      include         fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass    php-upstream;
    }

    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/stub-status.conf;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/default-*.conf;
}
```

Accessing `http://localhost` shows up the `index` page but without styles or any JS file loaded. I am not able to find what's is preventing the static files to be accessed.

Here is the output of `ls -la` command in the host (remember this is a Docker container running PHP-FPM and Nginx):

```
$ ls -la ~/dev/
total 96
drwxrwxr-x  11     80     80 4096 Dec 15 14:36 .
drwx------. 40 rperez rperez 4096 Dec 15 15:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x   5     80     80 4096 Mar 13  2015 css
drwxr-xr-x   7     80     80 4096 Aug  5  2015 demos
drwxr-xr-x   6     80     80 4096 Mar 26  2015 js
drwxr-xr-x   2     80     80 4096 Mar 27  2015 northwindSQL
drwxr-xr-x   4     80     80 4096 Mar 16  2015 php
```

The permissions are coming from Docker (weird to me but I have open another [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172253/docker-is-changing-files-ownership-and-permission-why) for that)

[This files](https://github.com/million12/docker-nginx/tree/master/container-files/etc/nginx) are from my repository and [this ones](https://github.com/reypm/another-lamp-docker/tree/master/php-fpm/container-files/etc/nginx) are from the repository where `FROM` comes in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/reypm/another-lamp-docker/blob/master/php-fpm/Dockerfile).

Can I get some help with this?

**Update**

As @Michael suggested I have check the Nginx logs on the container and I can see the following:

```
php71-fpm-nginx | 2016-12-15 20:02:40,483 DEBG 'nginx' stderr output:
php71-fpm-nginx | 2016/12/15 20:02:40 [error] 33#33: *46 open() "/data/www/demos/jqgrid/css/jquery-ui.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.20.0.1, server: , request: "GET /css/jquery-ui.css HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/index.php"
php71-fpm-nginx | 
php71-fpm-nginx | 2016-12-15 20:02:40,830 DEBG 'nginx' stderr output:
php71-fpm-nginx | 2016/12/15 20:02:40 [error] 33#33: *46 open() "/data/www/demos/jqgrid/css/control_icon.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.20.0.1, server: , request: "GET /css/control_icon.png HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/index.php"
php71-fpm-nginx |
```

But how that can be possible if the code says the opposite?

```
<script src="../../js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: You can't use `..` to back up above the document root.

Comment: @MichaelHampton this isn't my code but then how do I achieve that? I mean the `document_root` is inside the `demos` directory I need to go back two directories in order to access JS/CSS

Comment: I would go find the developer and ask them what on earth they were thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application has been developed so that your document root has to be:

root /data/www/demos/jqgrid;

And then you would access the application with URL `http://www.example.com/demos/jqgrid`. Why it has been developed like this, you have to ask the people who did it.